# Is it any reason why 'map' in jQuery works differently as static and instance method?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning `jQuery` right now and was surprised that `map` method has different order for same parameters in callback if it's called on `jQuery` object or on generic iterable. If i call `map` on `jQuery` object, callback will be passed object index first and object value second:

```
$( 'div:lt(5)' ).map( function( i, j ) { console.log( index, object ); } );
```

But if i call `map` for a list or dict, callback arguments are reversed! Object goes first and index second:

```
$.map( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], function( i, j ) { console.log( object, index ); } );
```

Is it any architectural reason for such inconsistency, or just a random hacking and no one cares?

Comment: Your examples don't make sense to me.

Comment: @Adder Sorry. What about text description?

Comment: @EyeofHell: [Perhaps this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hM6HT/) will help people understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map) function was available in version 1.0, whereas the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) function was added in jQuery 1.2. I assume one order was chosen for `jQuery.map()` (value, index), and then when `.map()` was added in jQuery 1.2 it was made consistent with `.each()` - and other similar functions - which which was available in 1.0 and used the (index, value) order.

This is purely speculation, though, and there may not have been any decision behind it at all. It also doesn't begin to address why `jQuery.map()` isn't consistent with `jQuery.each()`, which uses the same order (index,value) as its instance-based equivalent, and was also available in version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I like @AnthonyGrists's answer but here's another angle.

I agree the different order of arguments is confusing but there is a kind of logic.

- With `jQueryCollection.map()`, you are more likely to want to specify the index as a solo argument because `this` is available as a reference to the collection element.
- With `jQuery.map()`, on the other hand, `this` refers to the global namespace so you are (kind of) more likely to want to specify the element as a solo argument than the index.

Unfortunately, the question now becomes, why do the two methods not use `this` in the same way? And maybe that's as big a question as the one we're trying to answer.

Totally rational - no. Underlying rationality - possibly.